# Tooltip doesn`t show up for highstocks highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while but without any success. I am trying to render a highstockchart.

javascript for graph rendering :-

```
 chartwa= new Highcharts.StockChart({
                        chart: chart,
                        title: title,
                        xAxis: xAxis,
                        series: series,
                        legend : legend,
                        plotOptions : plotoptions,
                        tooltip : {shared: true},
                        datagrouping : {enabled : true}
                    });
```

Example data that i pass to the javascript :-

```
    series : [{'type': 'line', 'data': [[1425445067000, -165.0], [1425445077000, 42.0], [1425445087000, 152.0], [1425445098000, 26.0], [1425445108000, -117.0]], 'tooltip': {'valueDecimals': 2}}]
    title : {'text': 'No Title'}
    xAxis :
    chart : {'zoomType': 'x', 'renderTo': 'graph_103'}
    legend : {'labelFormat': '<span style="color:{color}">{name}</span> - <b> x : ({point.x:.2f}) , </b> y : ({point.y:.2f}) <br/>', 'layout': 'vertical', 'enabled': 'true', 'maxHeight': '100'}
    plotoptions : {'area': {'marker': {'lineWidth': 1, 'lineColor': '#666666'}, 'lineWidth': 1, 'percent': 'normal', 'lineColor': '#666666'}}
tooltip : {shared: true}
datagrouping : {enabled : true}
```

I am not sure why the tooltip doesn`t show up.

I am loading the js from

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/value-in-legend/master/value-in-legend.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/RolandBanguiran/highstock-zoom-out-selection/master/zoomout-selection.js"></script>
```

I see no errors in the debugger console.

Comment: Found the problem it was  due to <script src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/value-in-legend/master/value-in-legend.js"></script>

Comment: It may be good idea to report bug on plugin github page and post it here, for future reference :)

Comment: Will do that for sure.